# Login to JS webpage from python

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, post

I am trying to login to a webpage which uses javascript to login. the page contains a file called "login.js" ad it has following method:

```
function onformSbumit(object, e){
  if (e.getKey() === 13 || object.xtype==='button') {
    var form = object.up('form').getForm();
    if(form.isValid()) {
      form.submit({
        method : 'POST',
        success : function(form, action) {
          var result = Ext.decode(action.response.responseText);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("userName", result.data.principal.userId);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("id", result.data.principal.id);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("role", result.data.principal.role);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("roleName", result.data.principal.roleObj.roleName);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("privilege", result.data.principal.roleObj.rolePrivileges);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("partitionid", result.data.principal.operatorId);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("partitionName", result.data.principal.operator.name);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("time", result.data.principal.time);
          Ext.util.Cookies.set("timeZone", result.data.principal.timeZone);
          var redirect = 'main';
          window.location = redirect;
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know which procedure has to be followed for login to this page.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options in my opinion:

- use the python module `requests` in order to perform the POST request.
- use `selenium` in order to simulate browser activity.

For more information: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) or [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).